# Can not understand why the error is

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got an error code: 1327.

```
Undeclared variable; order_id.
```

I been looking at the code for hours, can not figure out where the error would.  I thought it might link to `Select last insert()..`

```sql
USE Data_Name

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE sql_error INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    SET sql_error = TRUE;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
    (DEFAULT, 3, NOW(), '10.00', '0.00', NULL, 4,
    'American Express', '378282246310005', '04/2013', 4);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()INTO order_id;

INSERT INTO order_items VALUES
    (DEFAULT, order_id, 6, '415.00', '161.85', 1);

INSERT INTO order_items VALUES
    (DEFAULT, order_id, 1, '699.00', '209.70', 1);

IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
    COMMIT;
SELECT 'The transaction was committed.';
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
SELECT 'The transaction was rolled back.';
END IF;
END//
```

Comment: I am going to state the obvious: order_id is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need a line in your procedure to declare the variable:

```
DECLARE order_id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
```

I choose the type as `BIGINT UNSIGNED` because that's the type returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Also, be sure to name that variable something that is different from any column name in your `order_items` table, or else the reference to the variable in your `INSERT` statement won't know if you mean to use the variable, or the column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace

```
 DECLARE sql_error INT DEFAULT FALSE;...

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
     SET sql_error = TRUE;...

 IF sql_error = FALSE THEN....
```

with

```
 DECLARE order_id BIGINT UNSIGNED;...

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
   SET order_id = TRUE;...

 IF order_id = FALSE THEN...
```

Next, focus on the INSERT statements and change to order_items1 and order_items2.

EXAMPLE:

```
 INSERT INTO order_items1 VALUES
     (DEFAULT, order_id, 6, '415.00', '161.85', 1);

 INSERT INTO order_items2 VALUES
     (DEFAULT, order_id, 1, '699.00', '209.70', 1);
```